# Shared Memory Fork Process Learning in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, process, fork, shared-memory

Good day to all! I am just trying to learn more about parent and child processes in Linux using the fork () function.
I am trying to make a very simple program where after setting up the shared memory segment, i can get a result from a child and output it in the parent .
My problem is it does not seem to work. Here is what i have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>     
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define SZ 20

typedef struct 
{
   int size;
   int cz[SZ];
}shared_data;

  shared_data* Collatz(int);

 int main (void)
 {
       pid_t pid;
       int seg_id,size=sizeof(shared_data);
       seg_id=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,size,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
         shared_data *sd=(shared_data *)shmat(seg_id,NULL, 0);

  int usr=-1,count,i;
  while(usr<1 ||usr >9)
{
    printf("Please Enter a Number between 1-9:");
    scanf("%d",&usr);
}

pid=fork();
if(pid<0)
{
  printf("Fork Failed");
  return 1;
}
if(pid==0)
{
    sd=Collatz(usr);
    shmdt(sd);

}
else
{
    wait(NULL);
    printf("\nThe Sequence is: %d ",count);
            for(i=0;i<sd->size;i++)
            {
                    printf(" %d ",sd->cz[i]);
            }
    printf("\n");

}
return 0;
 }



shared_data* Collatz(int val)
{
    int i=0;
    shared_data *data=malloc(sizeof(shared_data));
    data->cz[i]=val;

   while(val!=1)
   {
      i++;
      if(val%2==0)
        val=val/2;
      else
        val=(3*val)+1;
      data->cz[i]=val;
}
data->size=i;
return data;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Bit vague

Comment: i apoligise i get not output basically from the parent side. From what i see its because the shared memory part in this case *sd->size does not have a value. So i am only assuming that i messed up somewhere or the shared memory was not configured properly or i messed up some code

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to the memory allocated with `malloc`, not the memory allocated with `shmget`/`shmat`. I'm not 100% sure what you intended, but it may be that simply changing the assignment in the child to the following would do the trick. (This will overlay the shared memory with the `malloc`d content that you initialized in `Collatz()`.)

```
*sd=Collatz(usr);
```

[Edit: I should add that your current code `sd=Collatz(usr)` is instead overwriting the *pointer* value you got back from the `shmat()` call rather than the pointed-to memory area.]